# Flat shaded triangles using the ModelBuilder?

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx, 3d-meshes, terrain-rendering

I decided to give the `ModelBuilder` a try but I cannot get rid of the smoothing of my terrain. So what I tried:

- Create each triangle individually with there own vertex position.
- Put each triangle in it's own `part`.
- Put each triangle in its own `node`.
- Set indices individually after vertex positions been set.
- Used `ensureTriangleIndices` and `ensureCapacity` to set the vertex and index count.

*Executable test*

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes.Usage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Environment;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.ColorAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.environment.DirectionalLight;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.model.Node;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.CameraInputController;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.MeshPartBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

/**
 * libgdxtestenvironment [2019]
 * By Menno Gouw
 */
public class TerrainBuilderTest extends ApplicationAdapter {

    PerspectiveCamera cam;
    CameraInputController camController;
    ModelBatch modelBatch;
    Model model;
    ModelInstance instance;
    Environment environment;

    //CreateTerrain createTerrain;
    // Hardcoded heightmap for testing
    private final int[][] heightMap = {
            {0, 1, 3, 1, 0},
            {1, 2, 1, 3, 1},
            {2, 3, 2, 2, 1},
            {2, 4, 2, 1, 2},
            {1, 3, 2, 1, 2},
    };

    @Override
    public void create () {
        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
        setEnvironment();

        setCamera();

        //createTerrain = new CreateTerrain(16, 16);
        instance = new ModelInstance(myModelBuilder(heightMap));

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController = new CameraInputController(cam));
    }

    private void setCamera() {
        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(0f, 7f, 10f);
        cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        cam.near = 1f;
        cam.far = 50f;
        cam.update();
    }

    private void setEnvironment() {
        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, .4f, .4f, .4f, 1f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(1, 1, 1, -.2f, -.7f, -.1f));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        camController.update();

        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
        modelBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        modelBatch.dispose();
        model.dispose();
    }

    private Model myModelBuilder(int[][] heightMap){
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();

        modelBuilder.begin();
        MeshPartBuilder mpb = null;

        // Build the terrain, I tried with one part/node and with one for each triangle.
        modelBuilder.node();
        for (int y = 0; y < heightMap[0].length - 1; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < heightMap.length - 1; x++) {
                mpb = modelBuilder.part("quad[" + x + "," + y + "]" + "tri-1", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.ColorUnpacked,
                        new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE)));
                mpb.triangle(
                        new Vector3(x, heightMap[x][y] / 2f, y),
                        new Vector3(x, heightMap[x][y + 1] / 2f, y + 1),
                        new Vector3(x + 1, heightMap[x + 1][y] / 2f, y)
                );

                modelBuilder.node();
                mpb = modelBuilder.part("quad[" + x + "," + y + "]" + "tri-2", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.ColorUnpacked,
                        new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE)));
                mpb.triangle(
                        new Vector3(x + 1, heightMap[x + 1][y] / 2f, y),
                        new Vector3(x, heightMap[x][y + 1] / 2f, y + 1),
                        new Vector3(x + 1, heightMap[x + 1][y + 1] / 2f, y + 1)
                );
                modelBuilder.node();
            }
        }

        // Try setting indices manually
        for (int i = 0; i < (heightMap[0].length - 1) * (heightMap.length - 1); i += 3){
            mpb.triangle((short)i, (short)(i + 1),(short)(i + 2));
        }

        // Try setting indice numbers
        mpb.ensureTriangleIndices((heightMap[0].length - 1) * (heightMap.length - 1) * 2);

        mpb.ensureCapacity(
                (heightMap[0].length - 1) * (heightMap.length - 1) * 6,
                (heightMap[0].length - 1) * (heightMap.length - 1) * 6
        );

        return modelBuilder.end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using `VertexInfo` but would still like a answer where I can provide raw floats straight into the `MeshPartBuilder`. I Also find it strange that in the example code in my question I provide 6 verts per quad and the mesh still gets smoothed, it probably merges the verts under the hood otherwise it could not smooth the mesh afaik.

Anyway, with `VerteInfo` I can specify all parameters.

```
            v1.setPos(x + 1, heightMap[x + 1][y] / 2f, y);
            v2.setPos(x, heightMap[x][y + 1] / 2f, y + 1);
            v3.setPos(x + 1, heightMap[x + 1][y + 1] / 2f, y + 1);
            v1.setUV(1, 0);
            v2.setUV(0, 1);
            v3.setUV(1, 1);
            v1.setNor(normal);
            v2.setNor(normal);
            v3.setNor(normal);
```

And then just provide the `MeshPartBuilder` with the `VertexInfo` objects.

```
mpb.triangle(v1, v2, v3);
```

For completeness, one does need to specify the part consist of these attributes.

```
mpb = modelBuilder.part("part", 
                    GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates,
                    new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture)));
```

And it is also worth noting that you should not create a new `VertexInfo` object for each vertex. I just initialized 3 and reused them for each triangle.